# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'account'

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I'm working on an Angular2 App and when I navigate to

`http://localhost:4200/account`

I get

`Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'account'`

my routes look like this:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: MyComponent, children: [
            {
                path: '', component: HeaderComponent, outlet: 'header', children: [
                    {
                        path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, children: [
                            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, outlet: 'login' },
                            { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent, outlet: 'signup' },
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: '', component: ContentComponent, children: [
                    { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
                ]
            },
            { path: '', component: FooterComponent, outlet: 'footer' },
        ]
    },
];
```

any ideas?
thank you !

**EDIT 1**
well i created this

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: MyComponent, children: [
            {
                path: '', component: HeaderComponent, outlet: 'header', children: [
                    {
                        path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, children: [
                            { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: NotfoundComponent },
                            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
                            { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: '', component: ContentComponent, children: [
                    { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
                ]
            },
            { path: '', component: FooterComponent, outlet: 'footer' },
            { path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent },
        ]
    },
];
```

and navigated to account/login and it takes me to not found
am i missing anything? maybe sth with my routrs or structure?

Comment: Why are you using named outlets for `LoginComponent` and `SignupComponent`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbaueri want to be able to navigate between them, is this the issue?

Comment: There should no need for a named outlet to get that. Named outlets are for kinda parallel navigation. Like for example in Gmail, the compose mail dialog with it's own menu and routes in addition to the normal routes for mail folders. It's quite a while that I last tried named outlets in route configurations (instead of from `routerLink` or `router.navigate()`) and I was not able to make it work.

Comment: I added an answer with what I think should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can't route to `account` with your current route configuration.

Either

- route to `account/login` or `account/signup`
- add a redirect for that path to navigate to one of these two
- add a route with an empty path

```
{
    path: '', component: MyComponent, children: [
        {
            path: '', component: HeaderComponent, outlet: 'header', children: [
                {
                    path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, children: [
                        { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: DummyComponent }
                        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
                        { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
...
```

Comment: `{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }` needs `pathMatch: 'full'`

Comment: Are you using `ng-serve`?

Comment: Also try commenting out this route `{ path: '', component: FooterComponent, outlet: 'footer' },` (named outlet, empty path and no children and no `pathMatch`)

Comment: no hope =S,, i just think it has sth to do with the named outlets but IDK,,, anyway I can give up on that if you have a better way to create a popup that changes from login div to a signup div,,, using the route, and underneath shall be the home

Comment: i other words
/ --> goes to home,,,, /login ---> opens the login popup above the home,,,, /signup --> opens the signup popup,,, above the home

Comment: I'd first try without a popup and only after that is working, try routing them using named outlets. There are several answers how to navigate to named outlets using `routerLink` or `router.navigate()` (which worked for me as well). Id try with these first before trying to add them in routes config (which I wasn't able to make work and didn't get a response in a bug report)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer hmm okay i will try `router.navigate()` thx man

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer do you have a quick snippet to how to use `router.navigate()` to navigate to it? thx

Comment: You'd need to check https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bangular%5d%20named%20outlet I haven't used it since a long time myself.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets might help